# Delphi - Query.Open vs Query.ExecSQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I have a few questions below, to make it easier to identify the questions, I will **bold** them and give a number to each question (Q1, Q2, Q3...).

Let say I have a table like this :

```
Table Name : MyCustomer
Table Fields : CustID (varchar 10), CustName (varchar 10)
```

Current records on MyCustomer table :

```
CustID | CustName
-----------------
C12345 | Bruce
C12346 | Tom
```

On Delphi, I need to do a select, then an update.

For example Query1.SQL.Text is :

```
select CustID, CustName from MyCustomer where CustID = 'C12345'

update MyCustomer set CustName = 'Tom Riddle' where CustID = 'C12346'
```

**Q1 - To achieve this, should I use Query1. Open or Query1.ExecSQL?**

Since there is SELECT statement on this query (that return 1 record), then I assume I have to use :

```
Query1.Close;
Query1.Open;
```

**Q2 - This way the CustName is successfully updated to Tom Riddle. Is this the correct approach?**

But if I add a statement that move Query1's cursor, for example :

```
Query1.Close;
Query1.Open;
Query1.Last; // <----- cause error
```

I will get this error message NEXT time I run something to the SQL Server :

```
DB-Library error 10038: Attempt to initiate a new SQL Server operation with results pending.
```

**Q3 - What is this error message mean? What are results pending mean? Why there are results pending?**

**Q4 - Is it ok if I use Query1.ExecSQL even if there is returned records from the SELECT statement? (I don't need to access the records, but I can't remove the SELECT statement from the query).**

**Q5 - From Embarcadero documentation :**

Note: Do not use ExecSQL for commands that return data. These include any use of the ctTable command type, SELECT queries, and stored procedures that return a cursor. When the command returns data, use the Open method or set the Active property to true.

**What is the reasoning behind this documentation? And what if there is INSERT / UPDATE / DELETE after the SELECT statement?**

Comment: I have to ask, why do you want to `select`and `update`in one command ? ExecSql does not expects records returned, only info about the DML statement, like the number of affected rows for example. The Open statement expects only a result set, but your second command causes the database to send rows affected in stead of a resultset. Yes you can use the Open statement to execute both commands in one go, but you cannot expect the results returned from the database to work correct in that case

Comment: If you don't need to access the records from the SELECT statement then, contrary to your assertion, you *can certainly* remove the SELECT statement from the query.  It isn't needed.

Comment: Well this requirement is weird indeed. But I can't change the query. It's actually used for another process and it's a large query saved on a table column as Text. My example just a super simplified form of this case. On a module I'm currently working on, I need to do similiar task so I think i will just use the query, but I encaunter problems I described above...Anyway, weirdness aside, is there any solution so I can do SELECT and UPDATE in one command without these problems? Can I just use ExecSQL (from my tests, it doesn't show any issues even if there is returned result from SELECT).

Comment: Since your last sql statement is a DML statement (in the example an update) I think using the ExecSQL would be the safest way to go

Comment: So Embarcadero's documentation "Do not use ExecSQL for commands that return data." is referring to last statement in the query?

Comment: `What are results pending mean?`  Perhaps include more real code to show what you're doing.  Did you perhaps leave the query open?

Comment: The code basically as simple as described above : there is a Query dataset with its SQL contain SELECT and after that an UPDATE. If I write Query.Close; Query.Open; Query.Last; Query.Close; Query.Open; on a button click then the "results pending message" will popup on last Query.Open statement.